# Jquery autocomplete is not working with dynamically added row ( inputs )

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

When i click and start to type nationalities  on  the JSON file is loaded with autocomplete. Thats ok. Preview : http://mijaumijau.com/forma-b/

HTML

```
<input id="tags" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
<div class="append"></div>
<div class="add-more" style="font-size: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; width:20px;">+</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({

        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "nat.json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },


                success: function (data) {
                    var tag_val = $("#tags").val();
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {

                    //filtering results....
                        if (item.nationality.indexOf(tag_val) != -1) {
                            return {
                                label: item.nationality
                            };
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Now on '+' ( add more ) btn im trying to add one more input field that loads the same json autocomplete file.

```
$(function(){
      $('.add-more').click(function(){
         var newItem = '<br><input id="tags" style="text-transform: capitalize;">';
         $('.append').append(newItem);
         $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "nat.json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },


                success: function (data) {
                    var tag_val = $("#tags").val();
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {

                    //filtering results....
                        if (item.nationality.indexOf(tag_val) != -1) {
                            return {
                                label: item.nationality
                            };
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }

         });
      });
   });
```

The Input field is added with .append but it wont load the json file to select the "nationalities". Ive tryed to append on new ID (#tags2) and it works, but then ill have to copy the code so many times i want to load on new input fields.

Is there a way to generate input fields on click that recives a new #ID ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Use class instead of id for the identification.
2. Use function to return the autocomplete object.
3. Use $(this) instead of selector.